# CRC32 checksum different during runtime and JUnit test

Tags: java, junit, crc32

I currently have a strange problem. I read a file using the following function, create an object from it and store the file content as a byte array in the object as well.

```java
public static Iodd readFile(File file) throws IOException {
    if (!file.getName().endsWith(".xml"))
        throw new InvalidObjectException("Not a valid IODD XML file");

    String s = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    Iodd i = new XmlMapper().readValue(s, Iodd.class);

    i.setFile(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));

    return i;
}
```

In the file there is a CRC32 checksum. During the runtime of the program I can reproduce the checksum without problems using the `java.util.zip.CRC32` class. But if I want to test the same way using a JUnit test now, I get a completely different checksum.

The test file you can find [here](https://ioddfinder.io-link.com/productvariants/search/11765). Please use the the XML-file without country code.

Am I missing something?

I have already checked if the byte arrays are different in the JUnit test and during runtime but everything matches. For testing purpose I created a MD5 checksum from the file content and check it with the MD5 from the JUnit test but they are equal.

### Function for interest

This is the function which calculates the CRC32 checksum. The method `removeStamp` removes the crc-value from the stamp tag.

```java
public static boolean isValidInternal(final byte[] data, final long checkCrc) {
    CRC32 c = new CRC32();
    c.update(removeStamp(data));

    return (c.getValue() == checkCrc);
}
```

### Update 1

I add a new class with a main and add an output to the crc calculation method.

```java
public class App {
    private final static String TESTFILE = "testfile-iodd-tv7105.xml";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File f = new File(Iodd.class.getClassLoader().getResource(TESTFILE).getFile());
        Iodd i = Iodd.readFile(f);
        System.out.println(i.isValid());
    }
}
```

Output from the IntelliJ Run:
checkCrc: 1195433981
CRC32: 1195433981
true

Output from the Maven test command in IntelliJ:
checkCrc: 1195433981
CRC32: 2019633554

Comment: can you put a reproducer on github ?

Comment: if you still want to have it in github, just let me know.

https://iversion.informatik.htw-dresden.de/smartproductionsystems/projects/arrowhead-tools/iodd-parser

Comment: I ran in my local from intellij unit test and wrote a main in iodd and ran looks like result is the same
checkCrc:1195433981
c.getValue():557217516
from main and unit tests

Comment: please check https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228121/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-65901674-crc32-checksum-different-during-runt

Comment: I see... I add my answer as Update 1

Comment: maybe this helps, good news, if you run the mvn test with "-DforkMode=never" it does not fail in intellij :) bad news it still fails in terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you. I hope the problem is solved now. `mvn test` runs without problems from IntelliJ and Bash.

The solution was that I set the following configurations for the `maven-surefire-plugin` in the pom.xml:

- `reuseForks`: false
- `forkCount`: 0
- `useSystemClassLoader`: false (surpress warning that this option is not used when reuseForks option is false)

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
        <forkCount>0</forkCount>
        <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```